# Physical meaning of the inner product of quantum states

Tags: electromagnetism, time-reversal-symmetry

I would like to ask a simple question about quantum mechanics. Let $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ two states in which a quantum system can be. Then, I can consider the following inner product:

$$
\langle a|b \rangle
$$

Does this quantity have any physical meaning?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Physically, the quantity $\langle a | b\rangle$ is the probability amplitude that a measurement will find the system in state $|a\rangle$, given that it was originally prepared in state $|b\rangle$.

To get from this to the probability, you need to take the mod-square, i.e. $|\langle a | b\rangle|^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I rephrase it as the probability amplitude that the system is in states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ at the same time?

Comment: Nope, this is different. The quantity $\langle a | b\rangle$ doesn't specify which state the particle is in (unless it turns out to be 1 or 0, in which case you can say with certainty that the particle is or isn't in the state $|b\rangle$ with respectively). In general, however, it concerns a *hypothetical* measurement, and gives probability that the state $|a\rangle$ will be the outcome of such a measurement.